# How to enable scrollbars in silverlight 3.0

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, scrollbars

I have set my canvas width to 1500 and height to 1600 in my xaml page in silverlight 3.0.

When I run the testpage I can't see scrollbars. So I am not able to scroll to view rest elements. I also need to set scrollbars for a grid.

How to enable scrollbars?

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add your components as children of a `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a Scrollbar through this code:

```
ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```